# Starting a react on a VPS on Godaddy.com

Tags: reactjs, ssh, server, vps

I have ssh into my VPS and created the initial react app on the server with `npx create-react-app test` . I then run command `npm start`

I then with another terminal that is also ssh, curl to `curl   http://localhost:3000` and receive the correct response.

I then close the initial sever that had `npm start`. I then redo the `curl   http://localhost:3000` and fail to connect.  Shouldn't the curl have been successful, I thought the VPS would run indefinitely as it is a sever?  How do I get this sever to continuously run after I close the ssh connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `npm start`, it starts a development server process that serves your React application.

To keep the server running even after you disconnect from the SSH session, you can use some process manager like `pm2`, `forever`, or `screen`.

But it's good idea to use `nginx` to run your project on the VPS server.
See this link.
[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04][1]

Comment: thanks, i was looking into nginx, is it correct that for nginx server, i won't need to start up anything. Nginx takes care of the build and start?  I read that i only need to have the "build" folder in the server and nginx will take care?

Comment: Yes, Nginx make your built project to run on the server.

Comment: would you by chance know this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78084600/vps-backend-server-seems-to-be-http-instead-of-https

Comment: Please check the answers, I hope that answer will help you.